# Make Nautilus "search" show icons instead of list

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, search

Can Nautilus be configured to show icons in the search results, like it did in 16.04, instead of a list, like it does now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch between list and icon views using the icons located at the top right corner (refer to the screenshot below), left one is for list view, right one is for icon view.

[image]